# Получение символа нажатой клавиши Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Несложно получить *ключи* нажатых клавиш.
Но можно ли получать *символы* нажатых клавиш?

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы получаете "ключи" нажатых клавиш (конкретная библиотека, которую вы используете).

Comment: @insolor На данный момент хотел использовать Pyqt5, но мне несложно переключится и на другую. Главное чтобы была возможность получать символы клавиш.

Comment: Что на счет [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)?

Comment: @ShamusRezol это будет работать не на всех клавишах. Мне нужна возможность обрабатывать клавиши нумпада, Enter, Shift...

Comment: Как на счет [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)? Вроде как позволяет все клавиши обрабатывать, в том числе и нампадовских.

Comment: @Дмитрий Ого спасибо, это то что надо!

Comment: с вашего позоволения оформлю как ответ, чтобы информация была доступней

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях было предположено, что пакет [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) решает проблему ТС. Так оно и есть. Рад был помочь